# Button at the right bottom of screen in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, floating-action-button, radial

What is this shopping cart button at the right bottom of the screen called ? Click for image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCYwA.jpg) Is it a floating action button ? which also expands [check the video](https://material.io/design/assets/1SlTir4qcIH6gcKn2ZwVzAF5dA20rFtHF/04-tutorial.mp4), how to implement it ?

Comment: You've seen this? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html And perhaps more google search will help, as there are plenty guides on implementation.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through Google Code labs, Shopping cart animation is not implemented.  I feel they used radial animation to show the transparent picture adding to the shopping cart  but not sure

Answer (score -1):

This icon is 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Icons/shopping_cart-constant.html
This Shrine app is implemented in Google CodeLabs. Have you checked its [git-hub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-flutter-codelabs/tree/104-complete/mdc_100_series) ?